# Allow specific characters using onkeyup in input box

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I want to allow only `a-z, 0-9,` and `. - _` character using `onkeyup` in input box:

I use this code:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');" required>
```

But now I can't write this `. - _` character

How to allow this? But restrict only special character like `@` `#`

My value is:

`sabbir@` --> only remove `@` character,

`sabbir_ahmed` --> its allow

`sabbir.ahmed` --> its allow

So I want to remove only special characters like `@`, `#`, `$` etc.

Comment: Just add those characters to your character class: `[^a-z0-9._ -]`

Comment: its not working while try @#$%^&*

Comment: I've posted an answer - you can try it out in the snippet...

Comment: got it. it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the characters you want to allow to your character class:

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ._-]/gi, '');" required>
```

Comment: thanks, @nick. Can you please suggest some regex tutorial for learning. I think it will help me to understand deeply.

Comment: @errors perhaps https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html? There are a lot of good resources out there. The best thing though is to go to somewhere like https://regex101.com and play - they have a good description of what the regex is supposed to do as you enter it.